# Animating the border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu which has a border bottom with 3 pixels so it has an appearance similar to that of an underline. I have 2 animations in mind for it but I am not sure how to go about including them. Either have the border fade from 0.0 opacity to 1 (full) opacity. Or have the border appear from left to right i.e. draw itself.

```
nav li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    animation-name: navhover;
    animation-duration: 3.3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes navhover {
1% { 
    opacity: 0;
}

100% { 
    opacity: 1;
}

}
```

Any answers would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say that in your case, you probably want [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), not animations. Personally, I would say that if you can use a transition instead of an animation, you should use the transition. Only use animations when you can't do what you want with a transition.

Changing the border colour on hover is trivial:

```
.my-element {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: border-color 300ms;
}

.my-element:hover {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

If you want the border to animate from 0 to 100% width, you can't do that with a border. But you can use a pseudoelement:

```
.my-element::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: orange;
  transition: width 300ms;
}

.my-element:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've created a demo that you can view here: https://jsfiddle.net/65pceLrp/

Don't forget that you'll also want to vendor-prefix your transitions with `-webkit-transition`, `-moz-transition` etc.